# python how to populate a 2D array with counter values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have initialized a 2D array (235, 451) using

```
grid = np.zeros((235,451))
```

A snippet of the array is:

```
a = array(Counter({(87, 177): 347, (72, 191): 335, (88, 178): 318, (68, 188): 318, (67, 188): 318, (67, 187): 314}),dtype=object)
```

I want to populate the following indices with the counter values and leave all the other values without a value as zero.

e.g.

```
>>> grid[0,0] = 0
>>> grid[87,177]=347
>>> grid[72,191]=335
```

My overall goal will be to then contour this over a map.
Thank you.

Comment: Why is your `Counter` instance in an `np.array` in the first place? And you probably didn't initialize your `grid` like that...

Comment: Only because I'm more familiar with using numpy, so I changed the counter to a numpy array

Comment: You didn't change it to a numpy array, you just put it inside one (the dtype is `object`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put your counter in an array and do

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

a = Counter({(87, 177): 347, (72, 191): 335, (88, 178): 318, (68, 188): 318, (67, 188): 318, (67, 187): 314})
keys = np.array(list(a.keys()))
values = np.array(list(a.values()))

grid = np.zeros((235,451))
grid[keys[:, 0], keys[:, 1]] = values
```